# getting xml:lang attribute with a sparql request

Tags: xml, rdf, sparql

i'd like to know if it's possible using a sparql query to get the language tag on some litteral in my graph.

for instance, i could have things like :

```
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="fr">Bonjour</skos:definition>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="en">Hello</skos:definition>
```

and i would like to have a result set with each label and it's corresponding language.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the "lang" built-in function, as described in the SPARQL spec (section 17.4.2.6 in the spec for SPARQL 1.1: http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/).  So your query might look like:

```
PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
SELECT ?x ?label ?language
  WHERE { 
    ?x skos:prefLabel ?label ;
       foaf:mbox      ?mbox .
    BIND ( lang(?label) AS ?language )
  }
```

Note that using BIND in this way requires SPARQL 1.1

Comment: Is there a way to have this attribute using sparql 1.0 ?

Comment: Finally found it, it would work in sparql 1.0 with something like



PREFIX skos:<http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>

SELECT DISTINCT ?label (lang(?label) AS ?lang) WHERE {
?data skos:prefLabel ?label 
}

Comment: That's actually SPARQL 1.1 too, just a more commonly implemented syntax.